# Проблема с совместной работой node js и серверной базы данных postgresql

Tags: node.js, база-данных, postgresql, сервер

у меня есть программа, встроенная в node js.
Цель этой программы - получить информацию из pos-системы кафе через api и отфильтровать ее по нужным параметрам и записать в бд.
Затем веб-страница должна вывести отложенные и выполненные ордера.
Когда я запускаю эту программу со своего локального компьютера и подключаюсь к базе данных postgresql на своем компьютере, программа работает отлично, но когда я загружаю ее на железнодорожный сервер, то она иногда очень поздно отображает подготовленные и готовые заказы на веб-страницу, а иногда и очень поздно. это даже не показывает.
Я впервые создаю такую программу на nodejs. Пожалуйста, просмотрите код и помогите мне исправить его, если есть какие-то неправильные части.
Я думаю, что код в целом правильный, но есть небольшие проблемы в коде, который добавляет, удаляет, обновляет новые данные в базе данных postgresql и сортирует заказы на веб-странице, пожалуйста, помогите мне это исправить.

Мой код:

```
    const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const axios = require('axios');
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const { DateTime } = require('luxon');
const { env } = require('process');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

// Add cors middleware here
app.use(cors());



// const pool = new Pool({
//   user: 'postgres',
//   host: 'localhost', // Typically 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' for local development
//   database: 'db',
//   password: 'password',
//   port: 5432,
// });

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'user here',
  host: 'host here',
  database: 'database here',
  password: 'password here',
  // port: 26243,
});

const apiEndpoint = 'https://joinposter.com/api/dash.getTransactions';
const accessToken = "token_here";
const waitingMinutes = 3;

async function createTableWithRetry() {
  const maxRetries = 3; // Set the maximum number of retries
  let retryCount = 0;

  while (retryCount < maxRetries) {
    const client = await pool.connect();

    try {
      await client.query(`
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
          id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          transaction_id VARCHAR(355) UNIQUE,
          product_id_count INT,
          finishedcooking_count INT,
          is_printed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
          finished_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
          created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
        );
      `);
      // If the operation is successful, break out of the loop
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the error gracefully
      if (error.code === 'ENOTFOUND' || error.code === 'EAI_AGAIN') {
        console.error(`Error: Could not resolve hostname. Check your PostgreSQL host configuration.`);
      } else {
        console.error(`Error creating table. Attempt ${retryCount + 1}/${maxRetries}:`, error.message);
        // Retry the operation after a delay
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)); // Add a delay (1 second in this example)
      }

      // Increment the retry count
      retryCount++;
    } finally {
      client.release();
    }
  }

  if (retryCount === maxRetries) {
    console.error(`Maximum number of retries reached. Operation failed.`);
  }
}

async function fetchOrders() {
  const client = await pool.connect();

  try {
    const result = await client.query(`
      SELECT * FROM orders
      WHERE NOW() - created_at <= INTERVAL '80 minutes'
      AND NOW() - created_at >= INTERVAL '0 minutes'
      ORDER BY transaction_id DESC;
    `);

    return result.rows;
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
}

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const today = DateTime.now().toFormat('yyyyMMdd');
    const url = `${apiEndpoint}?token=${accessToken}&dateFrom=${today}&dateTo=${today}&include_history=true`;
    const response = await axios.get(url, { timeout: 20000 });
    const data = response.data;

    return data;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return null;
  }
}

async function insertOrUpdateData(data) {
  const client = await pool.connect();

  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN');

    for (const transaction of data.response) {
      const transactionId = transaction.transaction_id;
      const productIdCount = transaction.history
        .filter((history) => history.type_history === 'sendtokitchen')
        .flatMap((history) => history.value_text)
        .filter((entry) => 'product_id' in entry)
        .length;
      const finishedcookingCount = transaction.history
        .filter((history) => history.type_history === 'finishedcooking')
        .length;

      await client.query(
        `
        INSERT INTO orders (transaction_id, product_id_count, finishedcooking_count)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
        ON CONFLICT (transaction_id) DO UPDATE
        SET product_id_count = $2, finishedcooking_count = $3;
        `,
        [transactionId, productIdCount, finishedcookingCount]
      );
    }

    await client.query('COMMIT');
  } catch (error) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK');
    console.error('Error inserting/updating data:', error);
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
}

async function markOrdersPrinted() {
  const client = await pool.connect();

  try {
    await client.query('BEGIN');

    await client.query(`
      UPDATE orders
      SET is_printed = TRUE,
          finished_at = CASE
            WHEN finished_at IS NULL THEN NOW()
            ELSE finished_at
          END
      WHERE product_id_count = finishedcooking_count
      AND product_id_count != 0;
    `);

    await client.query('COMMIT');

  } catch (error) {
    await client.query('ROLLBACK');
    console.error('Error marking orders as printed:', error);
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
}

async function deleteOldFinishedOrders() {
  const client = await pool.connect();

  try {
    const currentTime = DateTime.now();

    if (currentTime.hour === 4 && currentTime.minute === 10) {
      await client.query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;');
      console.log("Table 'orders' dropped at 4:10 AM");

      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

      await client.query(`
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders (
          id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
          transaction_id VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
          product_id_count INT,
          finishedcooking_count INT,
          is_printed BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
          finished_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
          created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
        );
      `);
      console.log("Table 'orders' recreated.");
    }
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error deleting old finished orders:', error);

  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
}

async function main() {
  while (true) {
    const apiData = await fetchData();

    if (apiData) {
      await insertOrUpdateData(apiData);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      await markOrdersPrinted();
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      await deleteOldFinishedOrders();
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  }
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const orders = await fetchOrders();
  const preparingOrders = orders.filter(
    (order) => order.product_id_count > 0 && order.finishedcooking_count < order.product_id_count
  );
  const readyOrders = orders.filter(
    (order) =>
      order.product_id_count === order.finishedcooking_count &&
      order.product_id_count !== 0 &&
      DateTime.now().diff(DateTime.fromJSDate(order.finished_at), 'minutes').minutes < parseInt(waitingMinutes)
  );

app.get('/fetch_data', async (req, res) => {
  const orders = await fetchOrders(); // Implement fetchOrders function
  res.json({
    preparingOrders: orders.filter(order => order.product_id_count > 0 && order.finishedcooking_count < order.product_id_count),
    readyOrders: orders.filter(order => order.product_id_count === order.finishedcooking_count &&
      order.product_id_count !== 0 &&
      DateTime.now().diff(DateTime.fromJSDate(order.finished_at), 'minutes').minutes < parseInt(waitingMinutes))
  });
});

  const htmlResponse = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Order Status</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="public/awlogo.png" type="image/png">
      <style>
          body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
          }
          .container {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0 auto; /* markazga joylashgan */
            padding: 0px; /* tepa, chap, past va o'ng yonida 20 px ichki padding */
            box-sizing: border-box; /* padding va borderni ichki qismini qo'shadi */
          }
          .yellow-side {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: yellow;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 1000vh;
          }
          .green-side {
            flex: 1;
            background-color: green;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 1000vh;
          }
          ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: -44px;
          }

        li {
          background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
          margin: 7px;
          padding: 0px;
          padding-right: 1px;
          padding-left: 1px;
          border-radius: 99px;
          flex: 1 0 200px;
          max-width: calc(12%);
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 45px;
          font-weight: bold;
          line-height: 0px;
        }

        .bolim{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 28px;
        }

        .tana {
          width: 1920;
          height: 1080;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body class="tana">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="yellow-side">
          <h1 class="bolim">ГОТОВИТСЯ</h1>
          <ul id="preparingOrdersList">
            ${preparingOrders.map((order) => `<li><p>${order.transaction_id.slice(-2)}</p></li>`).join('')}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="green-side">
          <h1 class="bolim">ГОТОВЫЙ</h1>
          <ul id="readyOrdersList">
            ${readyOrders.map((order) => `<li><p>${order.transaction_id.slice(-2)}</p></li>`).join('')}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script>
      async function fetchDataAndUpdate() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('/fetch_data');
          if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            updateOrdersList(data.preparingOrders, 'preparingOrdersList');
            updateOrdersList(data.readyOrders, 'readyOrdersList');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
      }

        function updateOrdersList(orders, listId) {
          const list = document.getElementById(listId);
          list.innerHTML = orders.map(order => \`<li><h3>\${order.transaction_id.slice(-2)}</h3></li>\`).join('');
        }
        setInterval(fetchDataAndUpdate, 8000);
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
  `;

  res.send(htmlResponse);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


(async () => {
  await createTableWithRetry();
  await main();
})();
```

Вот некоторые ошибки, возникшие в ходе тестирования после загрузки приложения на железнодорожный сервер:

```
    2024-02-19 21:20:50.698 UTC [8] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432

2024-02-19 21:20:50.698 UTC [8] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

2024-02-19 21:20:50.712 UTC [8] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

2024-02-19 21:20:50.718 UTC [78] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-19 21:20:50 UTC

2024-02-19 21:20:50.724 UTC [8] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

2024-02-19 21:25:50.815 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time

2024-02-19 21:25:55.047 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 45 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.221 s, sync=0.005 s, total=4.233 s; sync files=12, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=261 kB, estimate=261 kB; lsn=0/1954508, redo lsn=0/19544D0

2024-02-19 21:29:29.138 UTC [105] ERROR:  deadlock detected

2024-02-19 21:29:29.138 UTC [105] DETAIL:  Process 105 waits for ShareLock on transaction 757; blocked by process 119.

Process 119 waits for ShareLock on transaction 755; blocked by process 105.

Process 105:

INSERT INTO orders (transaction_id, product_id_count, finishedcooking_count)

VALUES ($1, $2, $3)

ON CONFLICT (transaction_id) DO UPDATE
```

Это ошибка в журнале базы данных postgresql в railway:

```
    2024-02-19 21:35:50.983 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time

2024-02-19 21:35:52.503 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 16 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=1.506 s, sync=0.003 s, total=1.521 s; sync files=10, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=508 kB, estimate=508 kB; lsn=0/1A334A8, redo lsn=0/1A33470

2024-02-19 21:40:50.603 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time

2024-02-19 21:40:51.717 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 12 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=1.105 s, sync=0.004 s, total=1.115 s; sync files=7, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=244 kB, estimate=482 kB; lsn=0/1A70838, redo lsn=0/1A707F8

2024-02-19 21:45:50.817 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time

2024-02-19 21:45:51.731 UTC [76] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 10 buffers (0.1%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.904 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.914 s; sync files=6, longest=0.003 s, average=0.001 s; distance=25 kB, estimate=436 kB; lsn=0/1A76DE0, redo lsn=0/1A76D98

2024-02-19 21:55:16.358 UTC [244] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

2024-02-19 21:55:16.358 UTC [119] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

2024-02-19 21:55:16.368 UTC [302] LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
```

[image: Когда программа работает правильно, она должна отображаться вот так, но иногда она вообще не отображается.]

Когда программа работает правильно, она должна отображаться вот так , но иногда она вообще не отображается.

Я думал, что причина сбоя программы в времени функций, работающих с базой данных postgresql, и всячески пытался изменить их время, но не получилось.

Я думаю, проблема в этой части кода:

```
async function main() {
  while (true) {
    const apiData = await fetchData();

    if (apiData) {
      await insertOrUpdateData(apiData);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      await markOrdersPrinted();
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      await deleteOldFinishedOrders();
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
  }
}
```

Comment: **deadlock detected** - У вас блокировки на БД. Похоже, что разные сессии пытаются обновить одни и туже записи, и потом начинают ждать друг друга. Тут надо отслеживать всю логику обновления записей + возможно после обновления нет явных коммитов, задержки по сети. Ну и мое мнение, что в самом приложении не должно быть `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` особенно в рабочей фукнции. Вынесите это функцию старта приложения.